# Local HTML containing SWF can't connect to the Internet

Tags: html, flash, actionscript

My Flash project downloads data from the Internet through a PHP page on my website. It works properly in the following environments, but it won't work when I try to test it with a local HTML file that contains the SWF.

My SWF can connect to the Internet in:

```
Adobe Animate Test (Ctrl+Enter)
Adobe Animate Debug (Ctrl+Shift+Enter)
Standalone Flash Player
On my website in HTML (www.myWebsite.com/myFlash.html)
```

My SWF CANNOT connect to the Internet in:

```
local HTML file containing the SWF (C:\test\myFlash.html)
```

Is it possible to use a local HTML with embedded SWF to connect to the Internet? I've been trying to get it to work in Chrome, MS Edge, and IE11, but I have been unsuccessful.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
  </head>
  <body style="background-color:#f0f5f8">
    <object width="1280" height="720" data="Main.swf" style="border:1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right:auto; display:block">
      <param name="movie" value="Main.swf" />
      <param name="quality" value="high" />
      <param name="bgcolor" value="#000000" />
      <param name="play" value="true" />
      <param name="loop" value="false" />
      <param name="wmode" value="direct" />
      <param name="scale" value="showall" />
      <param name="menu" value="false" />
      <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
      <param name="salign" value="" />
      <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
      <param name="allowFullScreenInteractive" value="true" />
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

Edit: I made my SWF output the error message, and now when I try to play it in a local HTML, a TextField displays "securityError - Error #2048". That seems to be in regard to having a crossdomain.xml on the website, which I do have at www.myWebsite.com/crossdomain.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<cross-domain-policy>
  <site-control permitted-cross-domain-policies="master-only"/>
  <allow-access-from domain="*" />
</cross-domain-policy>
```

Comment: Go to the relevant settings page and add the folder where you keep HTML + SWF a trusted location: https://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Comment: **(1)** Is your `Stand-Alone Flash Player` also the PPAPI version (as used by Chrome and Edge)? [Download the SA Player](https://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/debug_downloads.html) here (get the `Chromium/Opera` debugger version for your OS). If yes then it should work. **(2)** Is your `.html` for displaying the `.swf` in same location/folder as the swf file itself? **(3)** I would've thought a _"Danger: local file talking to the internet here"_ security issue was the problem, but you say same swf works fine from same local folder when using the SA version. Will test this later...

Comment: Thanks, but I had already used that Macromedia page and added the trusted location. I had to do that in order to avoid sandbox security violations in the Adobe Animate Debugger. When I try to open my local HTML in Chrome, I'm not getting any error messages from the browser, although I probably need to make my SWF output some error messages to see what's going on. As for the Stand-Alone Flash Player, I'm using flashplayer_32_sa.exe from that page, which works fine. But that wouldn't affect how Chrome plays Flash, would it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had to change this line in my crossdomain.xml from this:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*"/>
```

to this:

```
<allow-access-from domain="*" secure="false"/>
```

My site is actually https://www.myWebsite.com/, which means I needed secure="false" so that non-https sites could access it.